# How to get formatted JSON in mysql like in sql we use FOR JSON clause

Tags: mysql, sql

how to create a query something like this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

but in MySQL, it shows error on the square bracket and if I use ' it gives output

query:

```
SELECT
  max(cpm) as [cpm.1],
  min(cpm) as [cpm.2]
FROM
  b.s;
```

and

```
SELECT
  max(cpm) as 'cpm.1',
  min(cpm) as 'cpm.2'
FROM
  b.s;
```

error on first
and the result of second is

```
[
  {
    "cpm.1" : 10.91,
    "cpm.2" : 10.91
  }
]
```

and the result should be

```
[
  {
    "cpm" :
    {
      "1" : 10.91,
      "2" : 10.91
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `for json` clause.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Here's a hint: You say you're using MySQL and you're reading the Manual for MS SQL Server.  That's like putting petrol in your diesel car, because your wife's car's handbook said so.  Read the correct manual...

Comment: Looks like you need [JSON_OBJECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) to create a JSON object from the results.

Comment: What your MySQL version if you use MySQL 5.5/5.7 you can use JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAY functions otherwise you need to make your own JSON formatting with CONCAT in combination with GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY..

Comment: I know `FOR JSON` in not work in MySQL. My mistake mention the wrong title. So how to get that resultant JSON in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the JSON_OBJECT function,
your code should be like

```
SELECT
 JSON_OBJECT("cpm", JSON_OBJECT("1",max(cpm),"2",
 min(cpm)))
FROM
 b.s;
```

Check this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) if you need some documentation.